# PHP 7: Whats bad about passing a non-variable by reference and why a NOTICE if function passed, but an FATAL error if array is passed?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, fatal-error, php-7

I have the following code:

```
$family = cis_resempty(wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'family'),0);
```

I get the following error:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   C:\xampp.....xxx.php on line 18

If I do the following:

```
$family = cis_resempty(array('a'),0);
```

I even get

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in
>   C:\xampp...xxx.php on line 16

The function cis_resempty is like this (but its from a library):

```
function cis_resempty(&$var,$key) { ... }
```

Found out that if I remove the `&` reference sign within the parameter list of cis_resempty there are no errors.

If I do this:

```
$family = @cis_resempty(wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'family'),0);
```

There is no notice and everything works - but Netbeans says:

> Misuse of the error control operator

But if I do this:

```
$family = @cis_resempty(array('a'),0);
```

The fatal error continues to exist.

Why can I pass a function by reference and suppress the notice with the error control operator but if I pass an array I get a fatal error?

Why is it bad to pass a non variable by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "non-variable" refers to any variable which the programmer cannot reference *by name*. These are temporary variables allocated by the executor at runtime: The result of a function call or some other expression, that is not assigned to a named variable.

To pass something by reference only makes sense if the variable being passed by reference is named, so that when the call is over, the caller can access that which was passed by reference to the callee.

When PHP comes across a function call at compile time, the space for the result of the function call, and parameters of the function call are reserved, and then allocated at execution time relative to the execution frame. When you pass the result of a function call by reference, the executor is able to force by-reference behaviour for the variable, because there is space on the heap and it can just ignore that the variable has no name ... it doesn't usually make sense to do that, but remains for backward compatibility reasons.

When PHP comes across a literal (array) at compile time, it allocates the space for the data relative to the op array (function) itself. Because of that difference forcing by-reference behaviour of literals would be dangerous and cause very unexpected behaviour: Consider what would happen when the function is re-entered, concurrently or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: **never** use `'@'` for suppressing.

> Why can I pass a function by reference and suppress the notice with
>   the error control operator but if I pass an array I get a fatal error?

Read here [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) first note:

> There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP **5.4.0**, call-time pass-by-reference **was removed**, so using it will raise a fatal error.

PHP doesn't "support" it since 5.4.0 => you get `E_FATAL` in any case. With `@` or without `@`. For function - you get `E_STRICT`. All right. Then, read about `@` work more here [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Again, first note:

> Note: The @-operator works only on expressions. A simple rule of thumb is: **if you can take the value of something, you can prepend the @ operator to it**. For instance, you can prepend it to variables, function and include calls, constants, and so forth. You cannot prepend it to function or class definitions, or conditional structures such as if and foreach, and so forth.

Try this code ( it will shed light) :

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 $arr = [1,2,3,4,5,];

 $a_closure = function(){
     return [1,2,3,4,5];
 };

 function a(){
    return [1,2,3,4,5];
 }

 function ref_func(&$input){
    foreach($input as &$in){
        $in++;
    }
 }

 ref_func($a);          // @ref_func($a); 
 ref_func(a());         // @ref_func($a()); 
 ref_func($a_closure);  // @ref_func($a_closure);
 // Fatals in both
 ref_func([1,2,3,4,5]); // @ref_func([1,2,3,4,5]);
```